# � при работе с substr()

Tags: кодировка, php

```
echo substr('ХэшКод', 0, 1);
```

Вместо "Х" выдаёт �. Почему так?

Comment: Преобразование кодировки. В win1251 выводите?

Comment: thunder, нет. utf8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция substr() однобайтовая... А у вас в UTF-8.

Для многобайтовых кодировок предназначены [mbstring](http://php.su/functions/?cat=mbstring)

Comment: @thunder, да. Спасибо!

mb_substr('ХэшКод', 0, 1, 'UTF-8');

Comment: пожалуйста)